# Calculation of reputation point is not correct

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-recalc

I check the total reputation point of my profile on stackoverflow. Yesterday it was around 2400+ and when I open today it become 2090.

[image: Yesterday Reputaion is 185 and in reputation tab it shows 55 only.]

In the above image you can check that on `Feb 17` to till date manu reputation added to my profile I am attaching the screenshot taken on Feb 18.

[image: Feb 18 reputation]

On that day my reputation was 2070 and after adding these much points it become 2090 only?

I check the other question related to this but it shows cache problem. But cache can effect yesterdays result not more then that i think but in my profile it shows status of last week i think.

I got `sqlalchemy` tag before 3 days and now that is not in my profile.

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug? Do all of the numbers listed in the "Reputation" tab add up correctly?

Comment: If i will add without bug then it gives error like `Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

must include one of these tags -- 'bug feature-request discussion support'
users with less than 500 reputation can't create new tags. The tag 'bugreputation' is new. Try using an existing tag instead.`

Comment: Your accounts page shows 2,598 reputation but your profile page says 2,098. You may have gotten recalc'd, or maybe you lost a +500 bounty somewhere? Who knows, but you lost 500 reputation from something (or maybe multiple things). **Edit:** Your accounts page has since updated to the new value.

Comment: Do you know any rule or something which will reduce 500 points ? Even my bounty tab shows 0 bounty :(

Comment: @Lafada: If your old posts have been deleted, you'd lose any reputation you gained from them. Perhaps you've answered a few questions which were closed as too localized, not constructive, etc and then subsequently got deleted?

Comment: Shall i check which posts are deleted which I answered ? Or is there any way to check the deleted activity?

Comment: @Lafada: Currently, that's not possible. Unless you have a photographic memory of everything you've ever posted. However, there are [upcoming changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) that will make this information visible to you (whenever you lose reputation due to deleted posts).

Comment: So there is no way to check where I lost my 500 points which shows in account page but not in my profile page ?

Comment: @Lafada: Only an SE staff member would be able to check for you. I'm sure when they see this someone will take a quick peek and tell you where it was lost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/471/discussion-between-lafada-and-animuson)

Comment: be patient... [Soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) you'll be able to see how much you lost from deletions, un-accepts, etc.

Comment: I have to add any tag to this post so SE staff will look into it or they will do automatically ?

Comment: I got `sqlalchemy` badge 3 days ago but now its not there :( My upvote for sqlalchemy was more then 100 and now its 79 only :'(

Comment: @NickCraver there might be but I dont have any query now :) No I dont want to discuss in public :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why this could be happening:

1. You've had some answers deleted - as you've noticed with your [sqlalchemy](/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) tag score reducing - which is why you've lost the badge.
2. You were the "victim" of a serial upvoter. Someone who went through your profile upvoting your answers because of who you were rather than their content. These votes are detected and removed automatically and a reputation recalculation is performed.
3. As Nick points out in his answer - When fraudulent votes are removed, a reputation recalculation is performed.
4. There are changes in train to keep your [headline reputation in line with your real reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) which means that your reputation will now go down as well as up.

Comment: yes but is there any way to check which answers are deleted ?

Comment: @Lafada - the new reputation pages will show you this - but I don't think it's rolled out fully on SO yet. You're seeing the the initial stage where everyone's reputation is recalculated to get a consistent baseline.

Comment: Thx @ChrisF I am accepting answer and hopping that i will not lose my 500 reputation again :).

Comment: @Lafada if any questions or answers are deleted you will lose reputation. It just won't be hidden any more.

Comment: I was wondering because in single day these much questions deleted from [tag:sqlalchemy] :)

Answer (score 1):

When fraudulent votes are removed, a reputation recalc is performed.